# Handlebars renders <p> as <span>

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have this html in my template:

```
 <div>
      <a href="{{pageLink}}"><h3 class="hvr-fade">{{Title}}</h3></a>
      <p>{{Comments}}</p>                       
 </div>
```

Now my page is rendered as:

```
 <div>
      <a href="http://link"><h3 class="hvr-fade">Page name</h3></a>
      <span>Hello this is my comment</span>                       
 </div>
```

Anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: Bear in mind you don't need to know if anyone else has faced the issue (a poll of 'yes' or 'no' is of no use to anyone, least of all you, I'd imagine); the question you probably meant to ask is: "*how do I stop this happening, and retain my `<p>` element?*"

Comment: You have invalid HTML (for HTML4 / XHTML at least), so you're probably just getting an unexpected result. `<a>` cannot nest `<h3>`. Doing it the other way around works though.

Comment: @Charles — That's fine in HTML 5 (including the XML serialisation of it which is modern XHTML), which has been stable for years.

Comment: @Quentin, handlebars.js maintains ECMAScript 3 compatibility, so it's probably irrelevant that it's okay _now_.

Comment: @Charles — As far as I know, Handlebars isn't even HTML aware (beyond a generic escaping routine)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xogofoh/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem